# Why does dynamic import preservers the origin?

Tags: javascript, dynamic-import

Say I have a script from a cdn with something like this:

```
// bundle.js at https://cdn.com/bundle.js
function loadModule(name) {
  return import(name);
}
```

I would expect that when including it in my application, I can use it to load my application modules without an absolute URL? because if I don't, it resolves to the origin where the script comes from:

```html
<script src='https://cdn.com/bundle.js'></script>
<script>
  // points to https://cdn.com/app.js instead of myhost.com/app.js
  loadModule('/app.js');
</script>
```

My question is: Is this a bug or a spec'd behavior? Would be nice if there could be further explanation around this behavior. I'm using Brave browser.

Comment: Yes, this is specified behaviour. The paths work just like those in a static `import` declaration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```js
// bundle.js at https://cdn.com/bundle.js
function loadModule(name) {
    return import(name);
}
```

desugars to

```js
// bundle.js at https://cdn.com/bundle.js
const scriptBaseURL = 'https://cdn.com/';
function loadModule(name) {
    return import(scriptBaseURL+name);
}
```